# C# double to integer

Tags: c#

Lets say I have the `double` 42.433243 and I would like to convert it to the integer 42433243.

What is the code for doing that when the decimal length is random?

Further examples:

```
45.25 => 4525

125.152254 => 125152254

etc...
```

Comment: No concerns about overflow?

Comment: What is the code that you have?

Comment: What do you want for `12.1`? 121 or 1210 or 12100....

Comment: No just quick and dirty. Its for some lat/lon pairs

Comment: decimal is very different from a double. Please make it clear which type you want..

Comment: @Matt dont be. Typically mindless downvoting results in upvotes to compensate. So now you know who is the gainer :)

Comment: @nawfal: I think the question is meant to talk about *decimal places*, unrelated to the `decimal` data type.

Comment: Hate all string approaches. If only i could down vote them all. @Matt accept Guffa's answer.

Comment: @nawfal Curious, why do you hate string answers? Go ahead and downvote. Free market system works.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true. Just 'cos nothing is stated in the question I would love OP ensures it. Thanks..

Comment: Its a toss up between John and Guffa. Guffa is more elegant, John's also works as this is a throw away project.

Comment: @JohnDavis you have some comments why for ur answer. Also don't you think approaching these "string" way is hackish? Always deal numbers as numbers unless absolutely needed. As for downvotes, my quota for the day is over :)

Comment: This will only produce meaningless integers. Even with lat/lon pairs there should be better requirements.

Comment: I understand that my answer only removes the ".", and periods may not be the only way to separate the numbers from the decimal values. However, I was curious why you disliked ALL string approaches. We could easily come up with a string approach that removes all non-integers. I'm not trying to argue, more to learn. Thats the only reason why I use this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can multiply the value by 10 as long as there are any fraction part:

```
Decimal m = 42.433243m;

while (m % 1 != 0) m *= 10;
int i = (int)m;
```

Comment: thats a novel way of doing it :)

Comment: What about  `42.4332430m`?

Comment: @Matt nothing novel, this is how you should ideally handle it, other than that the precision troubles you will end up with. doubles are dangerous to convert to other types like integers.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
double x = 42.25;
int big = int.Parse(x.ToString().Replace(".",""));
```

This doesn't work if the number is too big (e.g. overflow, bigger than 2^32 for int, or you could replace `int` with `double` on line 2 and get it a lot larger).

Let me know if you have other considerations.

Comment: Nice. Beat me to it, and even a little more elegant.

Comment: Doesn't work if your system's decimal separator is not `.` ... also, it is always rather inelegant to convert a number to a string and back to a number.

Comment: That was a lot simpler... I was overthinking this one :)

Comment: Is their something wrong with just casting, or using `convert`? Purely curious

Comment: Good point @O.R.Mapper, I'll think of a more mathematical answer to solve that problem, but this might work for the question poster.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would work.

```
while ((double_num - Math.floor(double_num)) != 0.0) double_num *= 10;
int num = (int) double_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(digits.Replace(".","").Replace(",",""), @"^\d+$").Value);
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the decimal separator is neither `,` nor `.`. Also, it is always rather inelegant to convert a number to a string and back to a number. Also, this answer lacks an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A more direct way to do this would be to convert the number to a `decimal` and examine the bits.

The first 96 least-significant bits represents the mantissa while the 32 most-significant bits represents the exponent.  So the actual value that you would be interested in is the 32 least significant bits.  The [`Decimal.GetBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) method returns the bits as an array ints so all you need to do is grab the first int in the array.  As long as the numbers don't exceed `int.MaxValue`, you're golden.

```
var number = 42.433243;
var asDecimal = (Decimal)number;
var bits = Decimal.GetBits(asDecimal);
var digits = bits[0]; // 42433243
```